# Cakephp returns empty but sql query has results

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, models

I have been fighting with this code:

```
function getNextActionFObyBalance($when) {

  $theQuery = $this->find('first', array(
   'fields' => array(
     'Contract.id',
     'Contract.start_balance'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
    'AND' => array(
      'Status.next_action_by' => 'frontoffice',
      'Status.status_type' => 'active',
      'Status.visibility' => 'frontoffice',
      'OR' => array(
        'Contract.next_action_on' => null,
    'Contract.next_action_on <=' => $when
      )
    )),
    'order' => 'Contract.start_balance DESC',
    'recursive' => 0,
  ));
  return $theQuery;
}
```

I have enabled logging on the MySQL server at this is what the server indicates that CakePHP is requesting:

```
SELECT `Contract`.`id`, `Contract`.`start_balance` FROM `contracts` AS `Contract` LEFT JOIN `statuses` AS `Status` ON (`Contract`.`status_id` = `Status`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Contract`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)  WHERE ((`Status`.`next_action_by` = 'frontoffice') AND (`Status`.`status_type` = 'active') AND (`Status`.`visibility` = 'frontoffice') AND (((`Contract`.`next_action_on` IS NULL) OR (`Contract`.`next_action_on` <= '2010-09-13 10:13:04'))))   ORDER BY `Contract`.`start_balance` DESC  LIMIT 1
```

if I use that in the phpmyadmin tool, I get exactly what I was expecting 1 record with two fields. **BUT** CakePHP just gives me an empty result set.
Can anyone enlighten me?

PS the code was working but I can figure out what changed!

Comment: Do you have anything in the afterFind method of any of your models?  AppModel, or the current model?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with a stub to do some post processing afterFind. The problem is that I have completely forgotten to return $results;
I found the error by doing a step by step debugging down the find method in model.php. Found that the after find was called at some point and went to check my afterFind. 
Took my about 4 hours for a simple error but I am learning!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this method is defined in models/contract.php?

The `recursive = 0` statement looks a bit suspect to me. Are the models correctly related in their respective model files?

Have you tried `loadModel` in case the associations aren't working properly?

It would be useful to see the relationship definitions from the respective models.

--EDIT-- 
I've formatted the code from your comment here as I can't edit your OP

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Status' => array( 
        'className' => 'Status', 
        'foreignKey' => 'status_id', 
                     ), 
    'User' => array( 
        'className' => 'User', 
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id', 
                     )
                 ); 

var $hasMany = array( 
    'Transaction' => array( 
        'className' => 'Transaction', 
        'foreignKey' => 'contract_id', 
        'dependent' => false, 
                      )
                 );
```

Comment: var $belongsTo = array(
 'Status' => array(
  'className' => 'Status',
  'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
  'conditions' => '',
  'fields' => '',
  'order' => ''
 ),
 'User' => array(
  'className' => 'User',
  'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
  'conditions' => '',
  'fields' => '',
  'order' => ''
 )
);
var $hasMany = array(
 'Transaction' => array(
  'className' => 'Transaction',
  'foreignKey' => 'contract_id',
  'dependent' => false,
  'conditions' => '',
  'fields' => '',
  'order' => '',
  'limit' => '',
  'offset' => '',
  'exclusive' => '',
  'finderQuery' => '',
  'counterQuery' => ''
 )
);

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. The method is indeed in the contract.php in models. Changing the recursive to 2 did not help either. What bugs me more than anything is that Cake is requesting result with the correct SQL from the server. But its still returning empty result set.

Comment: That code is in the Contract model, I guess. What does the Status model look like?